# unable to locate packages lib32bz2-1.0 ,libXt6:i386 , libXp6:i386 and libmwsgl.so in ubuntu 16.04 please help me

Tags: 16.04

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 libxi6 libxtst6 libxrender1 libxtst6:i386 libXp6:i386 libXt6:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lib32bz2-1.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'lib32bz2-1.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lib32bz2-1.0'
E: Unable to locate package libXp6:i386
E: Unable to locate package libXt6:i386
```

Comment: The guide you are following (please include a link in your question) is valid for Ubuntu 14.04. These package names are not valid in later releases. I suppose `libbz2-1.0:i386` can be used instead of `lib32bz2-1.0` but cannot find the successor of [`libXp6`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libxp6). However, [`libxt6`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libxt6) (with lowercase `x`) still exists for 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

have the reflex of doing package search : `apt-cache search <package>`

```
apt-cache search bz | grep -i 'lib'
apt-cache search ncurses
....
```